# How to data list to model and model's data send with one post process from view to controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

My model(dto);

```
public class DTOExample
            {
                #region Properties

                [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
                [DataType(DataType.Text)]
                [Display(Name = "Name")]
                public string Name{ get; set; }

                [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
                [StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı en az {1}, en çok {2} karakter olabilir.", MinimumLength = 12)]
                [DataType(DataType.Text)]
                [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
                public string LastName{ get; set; }

                [Display(Name = "Send Information")]
                public List<DTOSendInformations> ListSend { get; set; }
    }
    public class DTOSendInformations
    {
        [Display(Name = "AdressOne")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zorunlu alan")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} min {2}, max {1}", MinimumLength = 1)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string AdressOne{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AdressTwo")]
        [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "{0} min {2}, max {1} karakter olabilir.", MinimumLength = 10)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string AdressTwo{ get; set; }
    }
```

My View (I have written the necessary parts)

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParcaliAlisIzinGostergesi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>            
                            </div>
                        </div><br />
//I have a table,for AdressOne and AdressTwo,I can enter data dynamically int he view                
<table id="tableSendInformation" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>Send Information Detail</tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:150px">AdressOne</th>
                                <th style="width:250px">AdressTwo</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            @{
                                for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListSend.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(l => l.ListSend [i].AdressOne)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(l => l.ListSend [i].AdressTwo)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>      
//my buttons;                       
<div class="float-right"> // my button(for AdressOne and AdressTwo)
                        <div class="col-md-offset-8">
                            <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" name="Add" id="Add"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                       
                            <div class="col-md-offset-8"> //my submit button
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="buttonSave" class="btn btn-primary" name="buttonSave" />
                            </div>
```

I want Name,LastName, AdressOne,AdressTwo(multiple records) data, when you click the button(submit buton=>buttonSave) all of this information send from view to controller(I want to submit at the same time).

I want to send both my data and list in the model with a single post.
How can I do that?

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: what programming language are you using? This looks like ASP.NET MVC w/ Razor syntax, but I can't be certain.